# Docusign: Unable to lock a tab for a particular participent

Tags: python, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am creating a composite template that has data tabs and two recipients. I want that One recipient can modify the fields, but the other user can't. I tried using the `locked` attribute. But when I set `locked=True` for one recipient and `locked=False` for another recipient it locks them for all.

Any suggestions how I can lock a tab for particular recipient only

Answer (score 0):

By default, each tab (field) is owned by the recipient that the tab is owned by. If you want a tab to modified by more than one recipient, the tab must be marked as shared.

You can use the [API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/) to experiment. You can then have the API Request Builder create the Python code for you.

So to have a tab be modified by one signer and not by another:

```
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
        {
          "email": "signer_email@example.com",
          "name": "Signer's name", // This signer can modify the tab.
          "recipientId": "1",      // Other signers cannot
          "tabs": {
            "signHereTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "anchorXOffset": "20",
                "anchorUnits": "pixels"
              }
            ],
            "textTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/sig1/",
                "locked": "false", // the tab is NOT read-only
                "value": "initial value in the field",
                "required": "true", // the signer must update the tab
                "tabLabel": "data_label", // The data label for the tab
                "shared": "false" // only this signer can modify the value 
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: thanks Larry, I tried this but the issue is that this hides the field for other signer. I need the field to be readonly for one signer and editable for the other.